# How to write list of file path in JSON object with no escape sequence

Tags: java, json, regex

As i am new in handling json object and writing data to it , I have problem in adding my list of file path as mentioned below to the json object where it add escape '\' while printing it on console.

```
     Eg: List of files:
        c://absbd/jdojo/kppl/sample.csv
     c://absbd/jdojo/kppl/sample1.csv
     c://absbd/jdojo/kppl/sample2.csv
     c://absbd/jdojo/kppl/sample3.csv

    Putting this list to json object: 
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("listOfProcessedFiles", abovelist obj);

    I am getting output while doing System.out.println(obj.toString()); as mentiond below:

 c:\/\/absbd\/jdojo\/kppl/sample.csv
 c:\/\/absbd\/jdojo\/kppl\/sample1.csv
  c:\/\/absbd\/jdojo\/kppl\/sample2.csv
  c:\/\/absbd\/jdojo\/kppl\/sample3.csv

I want the o/p as :

    c://absbd/jdojo/kppl/sample.csv
     c://absbd/jdojo/kppl/sample1.csv
     c://absbd/jdojo/kppl/sample2.csv
     c://absbd/jdojo/kppl/sample3.csv
```

Please help.

Comment: what json package are you using?

Comment: import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

Comment: try `org.json.JSONArray` , `org.json.JSONObject`  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm